# How do I disable notification emails in Magento?

Tags: email, magento, notifications

How do I disable a particular notification email, for example the welcome email when a user creates an account?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no buit-in ability to disable particular email notifications in Magento. I suggest you to look at the **Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template::sendTransactional** method. You can overload this class and add check against allowed/disallowed email notifications (based on template name).

Update: you can use [extension](https://magery-themes.com/disable-email-notifications.html) for disabling specific email notifications in Magento 1.

Also, there is [Disable Emails](https://magery-themes.com/disable-email-notifications-magento2.html) extension for Magento 2.

Comment: ok,
in the case of newsletter magento use de class for rewrite the Mage_Newsletter_Model_Subscriber and for "welcome email" anyone knows the correct class to rewrite?

Answer (score 28):

We can disable all email communication in Magento by

- Login to Magento backend
- Go to the System->Configuration menu.
- On the left hand menu under the Advanced tab (at the bottom) select the System menu item.
- Select ‘Mail Sending Settings’ from the selection on the right hand side.
- Set Disable email communications to
  ‘Yes’, then no email will send
  through Magento.

Comment: This will disable ALL email notifications.

Comment: ok, I found it, how to send the notification email with the normal information about email and password of registration process.
In this email I have the activation link of the new account.
So I didn't wanna that customer receive another email "welcome email" with confirmation activation, so I just add this code in my local Customer.php

   public function sendNewAccountEmail($type = 'registered', $backUrl = '', $storeId = '0')
    {
        // This condition is to avoid send the welcome email to customer in account creation
        if($type == 'confirmed'){
            return $this;
        }

Comment: I want to disable only the new order Email that's send to the customer. I still don't find how can I do that.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You can Disable Sales Related Email communcation Like send mail on new order arrive..

From System->Configuration
        Select Sales Email from Sales Tab:

Set your setting in order tab for order mail setting

Answer (score 4):

See:

`admin/system_config/edit/section/sales_email/`

You can enable/disable all the transaction emails as you want with the exception of the create account email.

I do not suggest that you disable the new account email. This is because it has their login details including password. It is not sent with guest checkout, maybe you need to make your store 'guest checkout only' if that is what you want.

Comment: Ok, perfect.
Thanks for advice.

Answer (score 4):

This is a feature in the configuration settings as of Magento ver. 1.9.2.1 (maybe earlier)

System >> Configuration >> Sales Emails >> Enable/disable individual emails.

Comment: This is great for other emails. Unfortunately, there is no option in this area to disable the new account creation "welcome" email.

Answer (score 1):

Magento 2.3:

Stores > Configuration > Advanced (at the bottom of the left vertical menu) > System

Then Mail sending settings > Disable Email Communications: Yes

Also, make sure you clear the cache from System > Cache management

There's another method, using the command line:

```
php bin/magento config:set system/smtp/disable 1
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

- 1 = Disable email sending
- 0 = Enable email sending

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by @Mage_user 's question I created extension that allows to [disable any email notification](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/catalog/product/view/id/12837/s/disable-email-notifications-8993/) in Magento. So, @Bizboss you can use it to disable new order email.

Answer (score 0):

In Magento 2.4.2, you can easily navigate to stores > settings > configuration. Then under Sales > Sales emails, you should be able to disable the notifications that you require.